# I Try intall openstack on ubunto 18 but when I use this command ./stack.sh didnt work

Tags: openstack, devstack

error /opt/stack/devstack/tools/install_pip.sh:92 download of get-pip.py failed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OBAK.png)

Comment: Well, obviously the script could not download get_pip.py. It's your job to find out why. I would start by checking if the host has network connectivity at all, and try to manually download get_pip.py. I might also check the code in install_pip.sh.

Comment: By the way, don't post text as pictures. It can be hard or i possible to read, and pictures are useless for copying code and for search engines.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because of missing `nameserver 8.8.8.8`.
Please add this on your `/etc/resolv.conf`.
After adding this, You need to update the system by using `apt-get update`. Then run `./stack.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answer is not working,please use `FORCE=yes ./stack.sh` instead of `./stack.sh`